# Celsius to Fahrenheit is resulting in 32 each time

Tags: javascript, html

The following code is resulting in 32 each time whether the input is 9 or 90 how can I fix it?

```
var celsius = document.getElementById("cel").value;
var fahrenheit = document.getElementById("far");
var btn = document.getElementById("con");

function convert() {
var frnht = celsius * 9/5 + 32;

fahrenheit.innerHTML = frnht;
}

btn.addEventListener("click", convert, false);
```

Comment: that's because the unary operator +32 is the only numeric part of your formula. input values are not integers, they need to be converted

Comment: [How to debug small programs](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/)

Comment: @Leilo Faieta: Nah, strings auto convert to numbers (js doesn't really have integers) most of the time: `> "100"*9/5+32; //=> 212`.  I suspect it's the initialization thing mentioned in Tushar Shahi's answer.

Comment: @LelioFaieta `9` and `5` are also numeric. Not sure why you don't count them. And multiplication will always implicitly convert both operands to numeric.

Answer (score 2):

Put celsius definition inside your function.

```
var celsius = document.getElementById("cel").value;
```

Celsius is using the same initial value every time which would probably convert to 0 and hence result becomes 32. Adding this inside click handler will call this every time and assign a value depending on the input.

Comment: Right. As written, the  variable `celsius` is being initialized before anyone has filled in the field, and not checked again when they click the button. You want to only look at the field and get the value when the button is pressed.

Answer (score 0):

```
var btn = document.getElementById("con");

function convert() {
var celsius = document.getElementById("cel").value;
var fahrenheit = document.getElementById("far");
var frnht = celsius * (9/5) + 32;

fahrenheit.innerHTML = frnht;
}

btn.addEventListener("click", convert, false);
```

Try this, the value are initialized only when the event handler is triggered